# Show that the second derivative of $y=(x^2−3x)^3$ is $6(x^2-3x)(5x^2-15x+9)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do you find the second derivative of $$y=(^2−3)^3$$  and show that it is $6(x^2-3x)(5x^2-15x+9)$

Every time I worked it out, I used the chain rule first to get the first derivative which is
$ {3(x^2-3x)^3}\cdot{2x-3}$. Then I used the product rule + chain rule but I only managed to get the expanded form of what I was supposed to "show" which is $30x^4-180x^3+324x^2-162x$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not try factoring what you got? Or just expand the answer and show equivalence.

Comment: This is apparently a re-submission of [this query](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051123/second-derivative-find-the-fx-given-that-y-x2-3x3).  My understanding, which could be mistaken, is that you are supposed to edit the original query, and wait for the query to be re-opened, rather than (in effect) starting a new query on the same topic.  Just so you will know, going forward.

Answer (score 1):

You did not get the first derivative correctly.

The first derivative is $3(x^{2}-3x)^{2}(2x-3)$ and the second derivaive is $6(x^{2}-3x) (2x-3)^{2}+ 6(x^{2}-3x)^{2}$. Factor out $(x^{2}-3x)$ to get $6(x^{2}-3x) (4x^{2}-12x+9+x^{2}-3x)=6(x^{2}-3x)  (5x^{2}-15x+9)$

Comment: Could you explain how you got the second derivative? step-by-step I can't seem to get the right terms

Comment: Apply product rule. The  derivative of $(x^{2}-3x)^{2} $ is $2(x^{2}-3x) (2x-3)$ and it gets muliplied by $3(2x-3)$ to give the first term in my calculation of second derivative. When you differentiate (2x-3) you get the second term.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
Set $u=x^2-3x$ and use that $\:\bigl(u^3\bigr)'=3u^2u',\:$ hence
$$\bigl(u^3\bigr)''= 6u\mkern2mu u'^2+3u^2u''=\cdots$$